# Deadlock with MemoryMappedFile streaming

Tags: c#, mutex

I have a small problem performing  MemoryMappedFile streaming.
I have 2 projects, one for sending bytes and another for reading bytes. Between these two processes should be a 2 second sleep timer.

I've implemented all of this, but when the software attempts to do the read it appears to encounter a deadlock. The code for both processes is below.

Can anyone help me find the issue?

```
namespace ProcesComunication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("AAB", 1024);
            MemoryMappedViewStream mStream = mmf.CreateViewStream();
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(mStream);
            Mutex mx = new Mutex(true, "sync");
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine("TEST");
                bw.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                mx.ReleaseMutex();
            }

            bw.Close();
            mStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace ProcesRead
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("AAB");
            MemoryMappedViewStream mStream = mmf.CreateViewStream();
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(mStream);

            Mutex mx = Mutex.OpenExisting("sync");
            while (true)
            {
                mx.WaitOne();
                Console.Write(br.ReadString());
                 mx.ReleaseMutex();  
            }

            br.Close();
            mStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To be precise, describe where/when the deadlock appears. Does the writing start at all?

Comment: The writer will crash on the ReleaseMutex call the second time through the loop.  It didn't acquire the mutex.  A single mutex isn't enough to synchronize the reader and writer.  You really want to use a named pipe here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and found simple solution, below is a code:
Thanks to all contributors for answers.

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;


    namespace ProcesComunication
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("AAB", 1024);
                MemoryMappedViewStream mStream = mmf.CreateViewStream();
                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(mStream);
                Mutex mx = new Mutex(true, "sync");
                while (true)
                {
                    mx.WaitOne();
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    var random = new Random();
                    var nextValue = random.Next().ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(nextValue);
                    bw.Write(nextValue);
                    mx.ReleaseMutex();
                }
                bw.Close();
                mStream.Close();

            }
        }
    }

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;

namespace ProcesRead
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("AAB");
            MemoryMappedViewStream mStream = mmf.CreateViewStream();
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(mStream);

            Mutex emx = Mutex.OpenExisting("sync");
         while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(br.ReadString());
                emx.WaitOne(2000);
            }
            br.Close();
            mStream.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to use a synchronization object (Mutex). MemoryMappedFile is thread safety between the processes. Don't use mutex. And control reader to it have data for reading.